# Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/javax.activation-1.2.0.pom 1s 321ms

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle

Скачал обновление для Android Studio , в итоге стала появляться такая ошибка

org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/javax.activation-1.2.0.pom'

При переходе по ссылке пишет - "Ошибка при установлении защищённого соединения"

До обновления все было нормально

Может, кто сталкивался с такой проблемой ? 
Как это исправить?

Comment: Предполагаю, что это из-за блокировок РКН =) С официальной документацией для разработчиков Android та же история. Подключился к прокси, попробовал перейти по вашей ссылке - всё нормально, скачался .pom-файлик